# Why does this object equality test fail?

Tags: c#

Take the following class and unit test.

```
public class Entity
    {
        public object Id { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this == (Entity)obj;
        }

        public static bool operator == (Entity base1, Entity base2)
        {
            if (base1.Id != base2.Id)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static bool operator != (Entity base1, Entity base2)
        {
            return (!(base1.Id == base2.Id));
        }
    }
```

---

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            Entity e1 = new Entity { Id = 1 };
            Entity e2 = new Entity { Id = 1 };
            Assert.IsTrue(e1 == e2); //Always fails
        }
```

Can someone explain why its fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are relying on an object reference for comparator:

```
public object Id { get; set; }
```

Replace

```
    public static bool operator == (Entity base1, Entity base2)
    {
        if (base1.Id != base2.Id)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

With

```
    public static bool operator == (Entity base1, Entity base2)
    {
        return object.Equals(base1.Id, base2.Id);
    }
```

Comment: I prefer object.Equals(base1.Id, base2.Id) to cope with null Ids.

Comment: (It still leaves the hole of when base1 or base2 is null, of course, but that goes down into other problems too :)

Answer (score 8):

Your `Id` property is of type `object`. When you construct two instances using 1 as the Id for each of them, you'll end up with two different boxed objects. You're then comparing those objects using *reference* equality.

Suggested changes to fix this:

- Change the type of `Id` to be of type `int` if that's appropriate.
- Use the static `object.Equals` method to compare Ids instead of ==

Either of these will work, but the first is preferable IMO.

There are various other ways in which the implementation could be made cleaner if you're interested, but I understand this may just be a dummy example. Just a quick list at a glance:

- You should be overriding `GetHashCode` as well as `Equals`.
- Your `Equals` override shouldn't perform a cast unconditionally, as that will throw an exception if the object is of the wrong type. If the type is wrong, return false.
- Your current == implementation can be simplified to just

  ```
  return base1.Id == base2.Id;
  ```
- Your == implementation should perform nullity checks
- It's generally best to implement != by returning `!(base1 == base2)` unless you want specialist behaviour.
- Overriding `Equals` in a non-sealed class can be problematic. Unless you're planning for inheritance, it would be worth sealing the class (IMO - this will probably be controversial).

Comment: The reason i was led to this problem was because i was trying to use the Entity in a Dictionary<Entity, int>...and Retrieve the Key. So am i forced to change the type to int if i want to use the Entity in the Dictionary class? –

Comment: If you're trying to use it as a dictionary key then you should *definitely* be overriding GetHashCode. That's absolutely *critical*. No, you're not forced to change the type of Id to int, but you should use Equals to compare Ids, not ==. You can just use the Id's hashcode in your implementation of GetHashCode.

Answer (score 2):

Because e1.Id and e2.Id are different Objects. Even though they have the same value, they are not the same object, so the base1.Id == base2.Id fails.

Comment: Ok - so if i change my Id to type int it should work...Is it not possible to override == on object types?

Comment: You never *override* operators, you only *overload* them. You override the Equals method typically.

Comment: It is because the compile-time classes of Id are an object, so it uses the default reference equality. == and != aren't virtual in the way you expect, the == method to use is determined at <i>compile</i> time

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of equals is just comparing the references, not the contents of the object.  You're essentially comparing two pointers, and since you have created two separate objects, your equality will fail.

There are several articles on how to correctly implement Equals, here's a start:

http://weblogs.asp.net/tgraham/archive/2004/03/23/94870.aspx

For database entities, you can do a shortcut Equals implementation by just comparing the database IDs, assuming that two objects with the same ID are considered "equal" in your system.

Answer (score 2):

Your Id is an object, not an int. For objects the == operator will not check for value equality.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Id property is an object.

The 1 (as an int) gets boxed into a heap object, but each 1 gets boxed into a separate instance. As Id is an object, the base1.Id != base2.Id condition checks for *reference* equality rather than *value* equality, which is what you want. Changing Id to an int, or using Equals() rather than != should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your `Id` member an `int`, it would work.  But as CookieOfFortune said, when you're comparing two objects, it is looking to see if they are the exact same object, not whether they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of Id to an int, or other value type.  The problem is that you are comparing 2 objects, which I assume is the problem that you overloaded the == operator to solve